# Banco de Dados em Português para Estudar

Tags: banco-de-dados

Olá. Gostaria de saber se existe algum banco de dados para estudar, mas que seja em português.
Estou estudando a criação de relatórios gerenciais com ferramentas de BI conectando ao banco. Mas como só consegui bancos em inglês, estou com dificuldades de interpretar vários dados e identificar as chaves pra relacionar corretamente.

Comment: Olá. Acho improvável que tenha. Não sei como te ajudar, recomendaria tentar direcionar suas dúvidas fazendo perguntas (em português mesmo) no [English Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com), que pode ter falantes de ambos os idiomas, e tendo em mente que as perguntas devem ser genéricas o suficiente para ajudar várias pessoas com as mesmas dúvidas e não visando suporte individual do seu problema.

Comment: Estava me referindo ao sistema SGBD suportar linguagem SQL em português. Sobre bancos de dados em si conterem dados em português, isso acredito que possa existir em algum lugar. No caso aqui do site esse tipo de pergunta é fora de escopo e tende a ser fechada.

Comment: muita coisa de TI está em inglês, linguagens de programação de mercado e bancos de dados também, mas não precisa dominar inglês para usar bem essas ferramentas, existem videos e treinamentos em português que ensinam a usar as ferramentas

Comment: Além disso muitas ferramentas de acesso a sistemas de banco de dados (chamadas de clientes ou GUIs) populares costumam ter suporte a vários idiomas, inclusive português (em menus, caixas de diálogo, etc), bastando baixar a versão adequada ou então configurando a que baixou.